# Getting an error while connecting to the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework and I am stuck with this error while making a connection with the database.

My model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCTest.Models
{
    [Table("Employee")]
    public class EmployeeModel
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string name {get;set;}
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVCTest.Models;

namespace MVCTest.Controllers
{
    public class Employee1Controller : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee1
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            EmployeeContext employeecontext = new EmployeeContext();
            EmployeeModel employee= employeecontext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeId == id);
            return View(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

My `EmployeeContext` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;

namespace MVCTest.Models
{
    public class EmployeeContext:DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<EmployeeModel> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My connection string which i want to connect to my local machine and DB name TMA:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeContext" 
         connectionString="server=.;Database=TMA;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But whenever I am running this code I am getting this error

> "The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This
>   exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the
>   OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by
>   multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext
>   and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

Can anyone please provide any help regarding this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `server=.;` should be the problem, if you want to use localdb change it to `(localdb)\v11.0;` [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Are you using normal SQL Server or Express? If Express, `.` doesn't sound right for the server part of the connection string, and you should use `.\SQLEXPRESS` (or `(localdb)` or similar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error message, it sounds like the `context` cannot be used in an action method like that -- perhaps moving it to the class scope like the most examples would do the trick?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVCTest.Models;

namespace MVCTest.Controllers
{
    public class Employee1Controller : Controller
    {
        private readonly EmployeeContext db;

        public Employee1Controller()
        {
            db = new EmployeeContext();
        }

        // GET: Employee1
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            EmployeeModel employee = db.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeId == id);
            return View(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "If you don't specify a connection string or the name of one explicitly, Entity Framework assumes that the connection string name is the same as the class name." So what you're saying is not true

Comment: It can get a bit confusing :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved the error and i made changes to the connection string as well added SQLExpress

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="EmployeeEntities" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Employee;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
```

EntityContext class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;

namespace MVCTest.Models
{
    public class EntityContext:DbContext
    {
        public EntityContext()
        : base("EmployeeEntities")
    {
        //#if DEBUG 
        Database.SetInitializer<EntityContext>(new DatabaseInitializer());
        var ensureDLLIsCopied =
            System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance;
        //#endif
    }
        public DbSet<EmployeeModel> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```